# Equivalences of converse of mean value property, with $u$ not assumed harmonic.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $u\in C(U)$. Show the following statements are equivalent:

$$ \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}u(y)\,dy=u(x) $$

$$\frac{1}{|\partial B(x,r)|}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(y)dS(y)=u(x)$$

I know that when the second equation holds, $u$ is harmonic by the converse of the mean-value property and so the first equation holds as well.

But for the other implication, I have no clue.
I've tried to set $$\phi(r)=\frac{1}{|\partial B(x,r)|}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(y)dS(y)$$
Then $$\phi'(r)=\frac{r}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}\Delta u(y)\,dy$$ Taking $\Delta u\neq0$, say $\Delta u>0$, we see that $\phi'(r)>0$, thus $\phi(r)$ is strictly increasing.
Now $$\int_{B(x,r)}u(y)\,dy=\int_{0}^r\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(y)\,dS(y)=\int_0^r|\partial B(x,r)|\cdot\phi(s)ds$$
but then I don't see how to continue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalence of these two conditions is very basic. It's not necessary to pass through harmonicity, the only relevant fact is that
$$
\int_{B(x,r)} u(y) \, dy = \int_0^r \int_{\partial B(x,s)} u(y) \, dS(y) ds.
$$
To see this, denote the function $f(r) := \int_{B(x,r)} u(y) \, dy$, noting that now $f'(r) = \int_{\partial B(x,r)} u(y) \, dS(y)$. The equivalence of two mean value properties translates to the following:
$$
f(r) = \omega_n r^n \cdot u(x) \text{ for all } r>0 
\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad
f'(r) = n \omega_n r^{n-1} \cdot u(x) \text{ for all } r>0.
$$
The implication $\Rightarrow$ is evident. Proving $\Leftarrow$, at first we only infer that $f(r) = \omega_n r^n \cdot u(x) + C$. But $f(r) \to 0$ as $r \to 0$ (we're integrating a bounded function on smaller and smaller balls), so this constant $C$ has to be zero.

Comment: Wow, that is indeed much simpler (and quite elegant at that) than going around to use the harmonicity. I wouldn't have considered simply differentiating the integral (thus $f(r)$) and almost immediately yielding the result this way, thanks!

Comment: I do still have a question. Why can we use the fact that $f(r)\rightarrow0$ as $r>0$ to show that $C=0$?, aren't we trying to show that our function equals $f(r)$?

Comment: As far as I understand, your question comes from a different intepretation of what $f(r)$ is and what "our function" is. I defined $f(r)$ via the integral, so $f(r) \to 0$ holds because $|f(r)| \le E \omega_n r^n$, if we only assume that $|u|$ is bounded by $E$. If we already know that $f(r) = \omega_n r^n u(x) + C$ for some constant $C$, then $f(r) \to 0$ shows that $f(r)$ is given by the formula $\omega_n r^n u(x)$.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. I did indeed forget that $f(r)$ is defined to be the integral. We are proving that the right implies the left, not that $f(r)$ equals its respective integral. Thank you!